# The \overrightarrow doesn't work

Tags: luatex, amsmath, arrows

The `\overrightarrow` for vectors doesn't work. Here is a mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfakebold}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare}]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range=]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
%\newfontface\normalsize{Arial}[Scale=1.2]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
If $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{CD}$ have  the same length and the same direction, we say $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is \textbf{equivalent to }$\overrightarrow{CD}$. If A and C coincide, and B and D coincide, then we say $\overrightarrow{AB}$and $\overrightarrow{CD}$are \textbf{equal. }
\end{document}
```

As one can see in the screenshot,the arrows are small and not as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfakebold}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare,\overrig\
htarrow}]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range=]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
%\newfontface\normalsize{Arial}[Scale=1.2]                                      
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
If $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{CD}$ have  the same length and th\
e same direction, we say $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is \textbf{equivalent to }$\over\
rightarrow{CD}$. If A and C coincide, and B and D coincide, then we say $\overr\
ightarrow{AB}$and $\overrightarrow{CD}$are \textbf{equal. }
\end{document}
```

[image]

To slightly enlarge the arrowhead, you can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfakebold}
\usepackage{firamath-otf}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[Scale=1.5,range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare,\overrightarrow}]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range=]
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1]
%\newfontface\normalsize{Arial}[Scale=1.2]                                                                            
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=up/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=it/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setmathfont{Arial}[Scale=1.1,range=bfup/{num,Latin,latin}]
\setsansfont{Arial}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
If $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{CD}$ have  the same length and the same direction, we say $\overrightar\
row{AB}$ is \textbf{equivalent to }$\overrightarrow{CD}$. If A and C coincide, and B and D coincide, then we say $\ov\
errightarrow{AB}$and $\overrightarrow{CD}$are \textbf{equal. }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The arrowhead is very small.  Can we do something about it?

Comment: @S.Venkataraman, I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I modified your answer slightly.\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[range={\vdots,\ddots,\mdlgblksquare,\overrightarrow}]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}[Scale=1.8,range={\overrightarrow}]

Comment: OK. No problem.